# Why Ampliy API folder does not show in Amplify

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-appsync-resolver

I am working with a new client, but it seems I can't find the Amplify Graphql API in the amplify folder. I used to see the folder when working with Amplify but in this case, after pulling the environment I can't see the folder.

```
amplify status
```

[terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld4vt.png)

```
amplify folder structure
```

[terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6LpW.png)

Comment: Are you sure that this client uses a GraphQL API? It doesn’t look like it because there is no schema in the backend/api folder. Is there are graphQL folder with statements in the src folder?

Comment: @juicy-g yes there is graphql folder in src. Whenever I have to make change I have to change in appsync console and run amplify codegen to fetch those changes. Is there any way to convert this into graphql API to localhost so I can work more easily

Comment: Did you run `amplify add codegen` after `amplify pull`? The other option I can think of is to download the schema from Appsync into the backend/api folder then run `amplify configure codegen`.